# GCD sync serial main_queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

```
-(void)test1{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    NSLog(@"start");
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread currentThread]);
    });
}

-(void)test2{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yaoye.serial", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    NSLog(@"start");
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread currentThread]);
    });
}
```

#### Test1 and test2 are executed in the main thread

## Test1 example:

the main thread is blocked waiting for synchronization function, block into the main thread of the runloop cannot be executed, lead to deadlock.

## Test2 example:

the main thread waiting for synchronization function is blocked,block into the main thread of the runloop, but no deadlock.<`2016-03-14 13:55:06.730 GCD[54320:12111593] <NSThread: 0x7fef4ac08810>{number = 1, name = main}`>

## queation:

Why not is test2 deadlock?

Comment: Why should the second one deadlock?  You're dispatching to a different queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `test1` uses the same main queue, whereas `test2` uses a different queue

Comment: I didn't make it clear. Now I'm updating my question.